# Swift onfinish load event of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm loading a pdf in `WebView` from my server with this code :

```
    webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, y, screenSize.width, screenSize.height-y))    
    let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlFile)        
    webView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))        
    webView?.opaque = false;
    webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()                
    webView?.scalesPageToFit = true;    
    self.view.addSubview(webView!)
```

This code works but how can i receive an event "onPageLoad"?
sorry for bad english, i'm italian(:

Comment: Check my answer once it give you batter understanding for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to implement `UIWebViewDelegate` like this and use `webViewDidFinishLoad` to know the page is loaded successfully, for that set the `webView` `delegate` with your `viewController` like this, and implement the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method inside your `viewController` like below example.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, y, screenSize.width, screenSize.height-y))
        let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlFile)
        webView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        webView?.opaque = false;
        webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        webView?.scalesPageToFit = true; 
        webView?.delegate = self// Add this line to set the delegate of webView
        self.view.addSubview(webView!)       
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //Page is loaded do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is looking solution for WKWebView, implement WKNavigationDelegate:

add `webView.navigationDelegate = self`

and then use:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

}
```

Comment: Don't forget add `webView.navigationDelegate = self`

Answer (score 2):

After `webView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))` this, set the `webView` to `self` (Write the below line).

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Implement the [webview delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/) methods.

You will get callback in `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)` on completing the page load.

```
   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        //handle the callback here when page load completes
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what to do ? sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail. Please [check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39143913/988169)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `effective` with ;

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {

 // Here your loaded codes.

 }
```